# Get Content Field Value in Article Page

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, publishing-page

Is there a way in Sharepoint 2007 Publishing, to retrieve a custom content type's column value for the displayed article. I want to show different colored ribbon images according to article type which is stored in a custom column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you place a FieldValue control on a Page Layout you can set this to display the value of a custom column using the FieldName property. For example:

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="CustomFieldName" runat="server"/>
```

Note you will need a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls at the top of the page before this will work e.g.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

If you need to perform some manipulation on this value then you can get the value in code by using `SPContext.Current.ListItem["CustomFieldName"]`.

Answer (score 1):

For a publishing page to get the column value I use the  following

This code i have written in a UserControl Placed in a Page Layout , and in the UserControl i wrote the following code

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

 PublishingPage currentPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem);

if (currentPage != null)

                {
                    string title= currentPage.ListItem["Title"].ToString(); ;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the folowing method to get the data from all publishing pages that have value in the "Page Content" field

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("[site collection url]"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/[Subsite]/"))
                {
                    PublishingWeb myWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
                    PublishingPageCollection pages = myWeb.GetPublishingPages();

                    foreach (PublishingPage page in pages)
                    { 

                        if (page.Title == pageTitle)
                        {
                            if (page.ListItem["Page Content"] != null)
                                    Label2.Text = page.ListItem["Page Content"].ToString();
                                else
                                    Label2.Text = "The page " + page.Title.ToString() + " does not have content in ...Page Content... section";
                        }

                    }                
                }
            }
```

hope it helps.